# Is there any limit on characteristics UUID in Android BLE?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have Bluetooth LE module having one service and 50 characteristic UUIDs in the service.

I am using BluetoothLeGatt sample application to show the characteristic UUIDs but the sample app shows me only first 37 characteristic UUIDs out of 50 and it does not show the remaining 13 UUIDs while my other iOS app shows all the 50 UUIDs. I want to know that is there any limit on characteristics UUID  in Android BLE? If there is no limitation on the UUIDs then how can I  solve the issue? please guide me.

Comment: Seeing a similar behavior.  Can only read the first 39 characteristics and the remaining characteristics are showing up as descriptors of the 39th characteristic.

Comment: Looks like this may be a known issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=76639